# Format number to show at least 1 decimal

Tags: sql, oracle

I have numbers with different amount of decimals - it may be exactly 100 or 100.65468151.
What I need - is to show it with at least 1 decimal (or more). So that if it is exactly 100 - it should be shown as 100.0. While 100.65468151 should be shown with all the available decimals.

How can I do this?
P.S. it may be converted to char if needed.

Comment: Can you show your current output?  Typically this is something handled in the presentation layer (e.g. in Java).  You would just send floating point data to the presentation layer and then it would handle the formatting.

Comment: I'd suggest you not to do this at database level; rather display the desired format in the programming language where you want to present this data!

Comment: Having a variable number of decimal points on output is a curious data format.  Can you explain why that is useful?

Comment: I just needed this for testing purposes - I need to compare exactly on the SQL layer (no JAVA/other presentation layer/etc.). Output table, which I need to compare to, has this format of data representation, so I need to adjust my query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems like an odd requirements, but you can use [`to_char()`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions217.htm#SQLRF06130) with a suitable [format model](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements004.htm#SQLRF00211); just using `999.099999999' wouldn't quite work though:

```
with t (n) as (
  select 100 from dual
  union all select 100.0 from dual
  union all select 100.6 from dual
  union all select 100.654 from dual
  union all select 100.65468151 from dual
)
select n, to_char(n, '999999999.09999999') as text
from t;

         N TEXT               
---------- -------------------
       100        100.00000000
       100        100.00000000
     100.6        100.60000000
   100.654        100.65400000
100.654682        100.65468151
```

But if you add [the `FM` format modifier](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements004.htm#SQLRF00216) then extra trailing zeros won't be included:

```
with t (n) as (
  select 100 from dual
  union all select 100.0 from dual
  union all select 100.6 from dual
  union all select 100.654 from dual
  union all select 100.65468151 from dual
)
select n, to_char(n, 'FM999999999.09999999') as text
from t;

         N TEXT               
---------- -------------------
       100 100.0              
       100 100.0              
     100.6 100.6              
   100.654 100.654            
100.654682 100.65468151
```

You need an appropriate number of 9s before and after the decimal point so all possible values can be rendered of course; and you may prefer to make the final 9 before the decimal point a zero. You might also want to consider using the `D` format element instead of a period `.` so it honours session NLS settings.

Or, let your presentation layer (application, reporting tool or whatever) do the formatting. You should leave it as an actual number until the last possible moment.

Comment: `FM` is what I've been missing. Thanks a lot! This will be already done in my final layer when I need to compare my output with the system one.